# App review page coming twice in AppStore while using Appirater

Tags: ios, iphone, appirater

I implemented the `Appirater` in my application.It works fine. But when i click on Rate this App button on `Appirater` popup, it navigates me to Appstore to rate the app. when i click on 'Write a Review' button in AppStore and again same Page is coming, when i click Write review button for the second time, then it is allowing me to Review the app. How to fix this?This is my code

```
[Appirater setAppId:@"AppId"];
[Appirater setDaysUntilPrompt:0]; 
[Appirater setUsesUntilPrompt:3];
[Appirater setSignificantEventsUntilPrompt:-1]; 
[Appirater setDebug:NO];
[Appirater appLaunched:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I had to move `[Appirater appEnteredForeground:YES];` from:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

to:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [Appirater appEnteredForeground:YES];
}
```

I had put it in the wrong place initially